# (Java) Alphabetical binary tree class doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm required to develop my own binary search tree class for an assignment. It's supposed to sort a data class (User) which contains two strings, a username and a password, and then later be allowed to search it against a text file by the username variable. I tested the files for the assignment using a TreeSet successfully and found that the search will return about 300 positive matches if the whole search file is used. I thought based on my prior work that my binary tree class would work, but no matter what it never finds any matches via its search function, even though I know that's incorrect.

Some info on the code that isn't shown here-

- The node (called BinTree) contains a single user class as well as a left and right node, as is normal.
- getUserName is a simple accessor which directly retrieves userName from the node's underlying User.
- the grow method is initially called on a manually created root node (b = new BinTree([first data from the file reader is entered here])
- Since this is a program handling usernames, case sensitivity is important.
- Based on the way the driver class is written, the search method does need to only return true if it finds a User with the correct userName or false otherwise.

Here's the (new) grow() method;

```
    public BinTree grow(BinTree root, BinTree newNode)  
  {
    if (root == null)
      return newNode;
    if (newNode.getUserName().compareTo(root.getUserName()) > 0)
    {
      if (root.right == null)
        root.right = newNode;
      else
        root.right.grow(root.right, newNode);
    }
    else
    {
      if (root.left == null)
        root.left = newNode;
      else
        root.left.grow(root.left, newNode);
    }
    return root;
  }
```

And here's the (new) search() method;

```
     public boolean search(BinTree r, String s) //search for a username, case sensitive
  {

    if (r.getUserName().compareTo(s) == 0)
      return true;
    else if (r.left != null && r.getUserName().compareTo(s) < 0)
      return r.left.search(r.left, s);
    else if (r.right != null)
      return r.right.search(r.right, s);

    return false;
  }
```

Like I said, I had done a simpler binary tree before (that only held single int values, not custom data classes) and I've tried various ways of writing these two methods, but I feel like there's one crucial piece of the puzzle I'm just not getting. Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @Diasiare and @c0der for pointing out the obvious issue that my code had typos regarding returns and left/right. I took that and changed the above code to reflect it. Upon running, the program still didn't seem to be working. I then wrote this show() method to print all the usernames stored in the Users of the tree.

```
public  void  show(BinTree    r)         
    {
    if (r != null)    
{ 
show(r.left);
System.out.println(r.getUserName());
show(r.right);
}   
    } // show
```

When I called it after updating and compiling everything else, it did in fact show that the list was populated with usernames in alphabetical order. Here's a small snippet of the output (there's a lot of lines)

```
ted@wisler.com
teddy@borglum.com
teddy@winkey.com
-->teodoro@harkin.com<--
teodoro@stranford.com
teodoro@talaska.com
teodoro@willette.com
tera@norise.com
tera@strevels.com
terence@lathrum.com
terence@morocco.com
terence@neidig.com
terence@rabago.com
teresa@chauvin.com
teresa@dockus.com
```

The one singled out with arrows is one I manually searched through the search .txt file for and found. All told, with this new information I've determined that A) grow() is working correctly, as it populates the tree from the file in alphabetical order, and B) search() should be returning at least one match. Therefore, I'm working under the assumption that the problem lies in search() still.

UPDATE2: Here's the context in which I'm calling search() for those interested.

```
try
      {
        BufferedReader fromPasswords = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("passwordInput.txt"));

        while ((line = fromPasswords.readLine()) != null)
        {
          System.out.println(line);
          if(b.search(b, line))
          {
            matches++;
          }
        }
        fromPasswords.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        System.out.println("Error while searching tree: " + e);
        System.exit(0);
      }
```

Comment: Everyone will be going to ask what you did? It would be good if you can include the solutions you tried.

Comment: Arn't you missing a return after `if (root == null) root = newNode;` ? `if (root == null) { root = newNode; return; }`. Also shouldn't  `root.left.grow(root.right, newNode);`  be `root.left.grow(root.left, newNode);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the search function doesn't return the result of the recursive calls, it should read something like the following:

```
public boolean search(BinTree r, String s) //search for a username, case sensitive
  {

    if (r.getUserName().compareTo(s) == 0)
      return true;
    else if (r.left != null && r.getUserName().compareTo(s) < 0)
      return r.left.search(r.left, s);
    else if (r.right != null)
      return r.right.search(r.right, s);

    return false;

  }
```

I would also like to note that this:

```
if (root == null)
  root = newNode;
```

Doesn't make a lot of sense. If root is `null` you end up inserting `newNode` as a child of itself. Additionally your method has no way to comunicate that the tree was empty.  I would recommend that you throw an `NullPointerException`, or make the method return the new tree. This will help if in the future you want it to be a balanced tree, in which case the root node might change. In that case the solution would look like this:

```
  public BinTree grow(BinTree root, BinTree newNode) 
  {
    if (root == null)
      return newNode;
    if (newNode.getUserName().compareTo(root.getUserName()) > 0)
    {
      if (root.right == null)
        root.right = newNode;
      else
        root.right.grow(root.right, newNode);
    }
    else
    {
      if (root.left == null)
        root.left = newNode;
      else
        root.left.grow(root.left, newNode);
    }
    return root;
  }
```

Additionally as c0der notes the line `root.left.grow(root.right, newNode);` should probably be `root.left.grow(root.left, newNode);`